# Maximum Materialized views that can be created in Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, materialized-views

What is the maximum number of Materialized views that can be created in Postgresql.

I couldn't find any documentation / limitations regarding the maximum number of materialized views that can be created in Postgres.

Thanks.

Comment: Over one billion, that's the max in pg_class. But that counts for all objects, including other tables, indexes, etc. Would be a nightmare to maintain...

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens, Thanks for your response, so assuming I have a use-case where I need to create up to 100K MVs, this should be fine, relatively to the max pg_class value. did I get that right?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t believe you really have a use case like that. Could you please share the case?

Comment: @FrankHeikens **10K** MVs, which is equivalent to the number of tenants.

Comment: And why would you need one MV per tenant?

Comment: @FrankHeikens, There is a a complex SQL statement that uses RECURSIVE / INNER JOINS  and UNIONS to show the tenant's entities and we would like to improve the performance of this statement by having the data ready to be returned to the UI.

Comment: It may sound a little simple, and most likely it's not, but try to simplify this complex piece of SQL, improve the query plan, add indexes if needed, etc. to improve performance. That would solve the real problem, instead of creating 10.000 new potential problems.